# Чтение float значений из бинарного файла

Tags: php, файлы, сервер, binary

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С PHP познакомился только вчера. Задача заключается в том, чтобы загрузить бинарный файл на сервер(3D модель в формате STL) и достать координаты точек, но почему-то когда я присваиваю переменным значения и вывожу их, то получаются нули. Может я как-то неправильно понимаю синтаксис или что-то в этом роде. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
<?php


$filename = "C:/xampp/tmp/" .basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']);
$emptyArray = array();
$normal = array();
$vertex1 = array();
$vertex2 = array();
$vertex3 = array();
$count = 3;
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
fseek($handle,84);
while (feof($handle)==false) {
for ($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++){
        $contents = fread($handle, 4);
        $normal[] = (float)$contents;
}

var_dump($normal);
print("<br>");

for ($e = 1; $e <= 3; $e++){
        $content = fread($handle, 4);
        $vertex1[] = (float)$content;
}

var_dump($vertex1);
print("<br>");

for ($d = 1; $d <= 3; $d++){
        $contents = fread($handle, 4);
        $vertex2[] = (float)$content;
}

var_dump($vertex2);
print("<br>");

for ($f = 1; $f <= 3; $f++){
        $contents = fread($handle, 4);
        $vertex3[] = (float)$content;
}

var_dump($vertex3);
print("<br>");

fseek($handle,2);
$sum = $sum + ((((-1) * current($vertex3) * next($vertex2) * end($vertex1)) + prev($vertex2) * next($vertex3) * prev($vertex1) + prev($vertex3) * current($vertex1) * end($vertex2) - prev($vertex1) * next($vertex3) * current($vertex2) - reset($vertex2) * next($vertex1) * next($vertex3) + prev($vertex1) * next($vertex2) * current($vertex3)) / 6);
$normal = array();
$vertex1 = array();
$vertex2 = array();
$vertex3 = array();
} 
 fclose($handle);
print($sum);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

`fread` читает байты. Приведение к числу `(float)` приводит числовую строку к типу `float`. Например, `"15.634"` к числу с плавающей запятой. А строка не начинающаяся с чисел тихо приводится к 0 - так сделано приведение типа в PHP.

При этом `(float)` не пытается интерпретировать набор байтов в строке как `ieee 754` кодированное число. Например, `"\x99\x99\x19\x3f"` не начинается с кодов, ассоциированных в ASCII с числами - потому приведение к числу считает что работает не с числом и выполняет тихое приведение к 0.

Для того что бы преобразовать бинарное представление байт в осмысленное значение существует функция [`unpack`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php). Для `float` используется модификатор формата `f` и получается

```
var_dump(unpack('f', "\x99\x99\x19\x3f"));

array(1) {
 [1]=>
  float(0.59999996423721)
}
```